# MacBook Pro 2012 black screen at boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery, hardware

I have an MBP 2012* [non-retina] I recently acquired.
It worked just fine for several weeks until I left it, fully shut down & not on charge [mode 25 iirc] for two weeks.

I assume the battery went flat. Battery condition prior to this was 'good' with ~450 cycles on it. I also imagine this figure was a bit optimistic on a ten-year-old Mac.

In this state, the magsafe would go green for two seconds then red. I left it a couple of hours & the light went green, tried to boot. I get the chimes, then the light goes back to red & no further progress.

So, I left it on charge for 24h.
The light then stayed green as I try to boot it, but after the chimes there is no further apparent progress at all - no backlight, no keyboard light. There is a very very quiet hum - possibly fans turning at absolute minimum; there is no HD, it has 2 SSDs.

*Update*
On occasion, after a few minutes of sitting just black, it's managed to run the startup 'thermometer' but then complained that I've forgotten my password. This would suggest I've ignored the FileVault prompt - which I haven't seen.
One time it asked my to provide any admin password to disable FileVault. I did. It said it would restart & be disabled.
It went back to chimes only, and has done only that ever since.
I've tried periodically typing my password after random periods after the chime. No change.
After some time - never accurately measured - it shuts down again & is ready to repeat the process.

It's now been on charge about 4 days.

If I could persuade it to Recovery, I have no qualms about just nuking & paving if that would cure it. Essentially the entire machine is just a 'copy' of data stored elsewhere.

<sup>MBP Mid 2012 15", 9,1, 16GB RAM, 2 x 500GB SSD. Last running Mojave.</sup>